How does the CPU interact with Hard Drive?
If the CPU can't directly access the Hard Drive, how does it communicate with the Hard Drive to load data into RAM?
Let's say a page fault occurs. How does the CPU know where in the hard drive that page is located so that it can bring it to RAM? How does it (the CPU) instruct the hard drive? How is the process carried out?
What is the case when there is a DMA and no DMA?
Also as ssd are also integrated circuits, why are they slower than RAM?
Please shed some light on these topics. I would like a detailed answer.
I know my question is very long but please help me. Links to good resources are also welcomed.

vimalathithan17 - This has been closed as it is a cross-site duplicate of the same question you asked on Computer Science.SE. Please don't repeat questions across SE sites as it duplicates effort & wastes people's time repeating the same work. See this FAQ article. || Also, the question is too broad. Questions on SE should be one specific on-topic question which includes your research and is reasonably scoped. Site rules on SE differ from typical forums.

@SamGibson sure I won't repeat it. But I find electronics stack exchange to be relevant so could you please open this question.Could you explain why is this question off topic?

vimalathithan17 - "could you please open this question" No, for the reasons I explained above.  "Could you explain why is this question off topic?" Please see the list of on-topic subjects I linked above. This site is primarily for electronics design, related physics & embedded firmware programming. Your question is not one of those. You could check the on-topic lists of other SE sites like Super User & Comp Sci.SE, to see if your question would be on-topic there. However even if it's on-topic, it may be considered too broad e.g. scope undefined, no research shown, multiple questions.

@SamGibson understood sir thank you.Could you suggest any resources fo learn these subject.

I have provided a brief answer to your original question.

@DaveTweed thanks brother read it just now.
